# How to resolve the keyError:4?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, keyerror

I need to extract the rank of a specific value:
This i my  out_dict:

```
 out_dict={'198': 2, '223': 5, '102': 7, '197': 6, '183': 9, '184': 3, '248': 1, '255': 8, '179': 10, '241': 4}
```

This is my  Key[BestByte]:

```
Key[BestByte]= 198
```

This is my code:

```
print (out_dict)
    for k in out_dict.values():
        if out_dict[k] == Key[BestByte]:
            print (k)
```

It gives me this error:  `KeyError: 4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're looping on the values, not the keys. Loop on the keys instead. And convert to integer to compare:

```
for k in out_dict:   # same as out_dict.keys(), even slightly better
    if int(k) == Key[BestByte]:
```

BUT looping on the keys of a dictionary to test something is a dead giveaway that something could be improved:

You're not using the dict power in that case. It would be better to do:

```
if str(Key[BestByte]) in out_dict:
```

avoids the loop, and the linear search. Now you're using the dictionary lookup with is much faster.

In that case, now to get the value:

```
if str(Key[BestByte]) in out_dict:
    value =  out_dict[str(Key[BestByte])]
```

or just:

```
value = out_dict.get(str(Key[BestByte])
```

and test `value is not None` just in case the key is missing.

Comment: Thank you sir for you answer but I need the extract the rank of the  the value, for  example if the value id '197 that I need to display the rank  6

Answer (score 0):

First up your indentation seems a bit off and everything from `for` should be at the same indentation as the above `print` statement.

As for your issue, `for k in out_dict.values()` will give you the actual values in your `out_dict` (i.e. 2, 5, 7, 6, etc.) rather than the `key` of the dictionary. Thus the `if` logic will not work as `k` is not a key of `out_dict`, producing your `KeyError`. There are several ways to fix this including:

```
for key, value in out_dict.items():
    if value == Key[BestByte]
        print(key)
```